# Is there a way make a Grails app aware of changes in properties file without server restart?

Tags: grails

I've externalized the properties file for my production Grails app running on Tomcat.

I'm wondering if there is a way the Grails app will read the configs from the config file in real time instead of having the changes take affect only after server restart.

For example, I'm using the LDAP plugin which has the following config:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'somethinghere'
```

If I change the above setting in the external config file the server needs to be restarted for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "grails external reload" and the first result was http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload